# Passing form values by id in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have major problem with my jquery and Ajax request as I am new at that.

I am doing CRUD operations and my add method works well. **Edit** is causing me headache.

I have an edit in mu route like */edit/{id}* and whenever button of the modal is clicked, modal is open but on 'save' it's 'undefined'.

U have few problems:

- ID is not catched.
- I want to display all current property values of form fields. This is my biggest problem, I saw examples but I was not able to figure out how to display all form field current values based on that ID.
- Form is passing on submit without any changes

So there are some thing

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#editModal', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).data("data-id");
    var startDate = $(this).data("startDate");
    var endDate = $(this).data("endDate");
});

$('#form-edit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var startDate = $(this).data("startDate");
    var endDate = $(this).data("endDate");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'PATCH',
            url: "/user/edit/"+id,
            data: JSON.stringify({"startDate":startDate, "endDate":endDate}),
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json-patch+json',
            success: function () {
                $("#user-table").load(location.href + " #user-table");
                $('#editModal').modal('hide');
                displayNotif('success', 'check', 'User updated successfully');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var ErrorMessage = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
});
```

In have defined that id in the modal launch button like:

```
<a href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data-id="{{ user.id }}" class="btn btn-warning user_edit">Edit</a>
```

Also form is set properly, as add form just with hidden ID field here.

Here is the dorm in modal.

```
<form class="form" id="user-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">

    <label for="startDate">Start Date: </label>
    <input id="startDate" name="startDate" class="form-control" type="date" value="" required/>

    <label for="endDate">End Date: </label>
    <input id="endDate" name="endDate" class="form-control" type="date" value=""/>
         
    <input id="form-edit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
 </form>
```

I am new with jquery and ajax so any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you add the HTML of your form as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to the `click` event on the `.user_edit` link. Now `this` will refer to that specific element and will get the correct `data-id` attribute value. Then with that value set the `value` of the hidden input element.

Then use the `submit` event to disable the default submit behavior. In it find the the fields that are children within the form and read the values from those elements.

Try the snippet below and see if any values are passed.

```
$(function() {
  $('.user_edit').on('click', function(event) {
    // Get the id and target values from the link.
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.data('id');
    var target = $this.data('target');

    // Select the modal the link refers to..
    var $modal = $(target);

    // ..and find the form inside that modal..
    var $form = $modal.find('.form');

    // ..to set the hidden input field with the id.
    $form.find('input[name="id"]').val(id);
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // Listen for submit instead of click.
  $('.form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the values from the form.
    var $form = $(this);
    var id = $form.find('input[name="id"]').val();
    var startDate = $form.find('input[name="startDate"]').val();
    var endDate = $form.find('input[name="endDate"]').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'PATCH',
      url: '/user/edit/' + id,
      data: JSON.stringify({
        'startDate': startDate,
        'endDate': endDate
      }),
      processData: false,
      contentType: 'application/json-patch+json',
      success: function () {
        $("#user-table").load(location.href + " #user-table");
        $('#editModal').modal('hide');
        displayNotif('success', 'check', 'User updated successfully');
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var ErrorMessage = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });

}());
```

Comment: Thank you for replay. But it seems that all other values are there except the id value. When i console.log it it's still undefined? @ EmielZuurbier

Comment: UPDATE: var id = $('.user_edit').data("id"); works. console.log return value but form some reason that value is not inserted in form hidden field? @EmielZuurbier

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the snippet and did some tests. The `input`'s value should be set now.

Comment: Thats working. Thank you. Do you maybe know why I can not update two different entites without refreshing the page. It always catches the same id that is first clicked? @EmielZuurbier

Comment: I don't understand your question, but this would seem like a new issue. Open a new question and mark this one as accepted for future users.